# Android: LinearProgressIndicator with Gradient color

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design

**What I would like:**

I'd like to implement a LinearProgressIndicator on native Android (Kotlin) with a gradient indicator color, where the end of the gradient is the same color as the track color. This is the desired result:

[image]

If you look closely you see that the start of the indicator is gray, moving slightly towards white in the center before moving back to gray again. This white gradient moves from left to right as any indeterminate progress indicator would.

**What I have:**

[image]

As you can see above there is a 'hard' cutoff between gray and white, and I would like this to become gradient. This is the default behavior of [LinearProgressIndicator (developer reference)](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/progressindicator/LinearProgressIndicator). ([Material.io reference](https://material.io/components/progress-indicators/android#linear-progress-indicators))

```
                <com.google.android.material.progressindicator.LinearProgressIndicator
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_default"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_default" />
```

With the colors from the styling definition:

```
        <item name="indicatorColor">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="trackColor">#F5F7FB</item>
```

**What does not work:**

I have tried creating a gradient drawable as described below but as far as I can tell the LinearProgressIndicator does not support drawables, only colors.

```
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient
            android:angle="90"
            android:centerColor="#F5F7FB"
            android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:type="linear" />
    </shape>
```

**TL;DR**

How can I implement a linear indeterminate progress indicator with a gradient indicator color?

Comment: I've never known that you can use a gradient, have you seen this somewhere?

Comment: https://uxdesign.cc/what-you-should-know-about-skeleton-screens-a820c45a571a
If you scroll down to the header called ''The Tests'' you can see a skeleton screen with some sort of animation. I'm trying to recreate something like this.

Comment: Yes, I'm asking where you've seen that `LinearProgressIndicator` supports gradients?

Comment: I haven't, thats why I'm asking this question

Comment: Oh I see, I don't think it does, if it's not mentioned in the documentation then I find it unlikely that it's a hidden feature.

Comment: Got the solution? I am facing the same problem too, the drawable approach works on normal progress bar, but for material one, it doesn't work...